# Data is lost on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, mern, redux-toolkit

I am developing a web application using MERN stack. I am using Redux Toolkit for state management.

I display a list of blog posts on the homepage.
[image]
When I click on the view button, I am taken to the page for that particular post.
[image]
However, when I refresh the page, I no longer see the post.
[image]
Why it it happening?

The following are my code snippets:
src/components/ViewPost.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const ViewPost = ({ match }) => {


  const post = useSelector((state) =>
    state.posts.posts.find((post) => post._id === match.params.id)
  );

  
  return (
    <div>
      {post ? (
        <div className="row mt-5">
          <div className="col-md-8 mx-auto">
            <article>
              <h3 className="">{post.title}</h3>
              <h6 className="text-muted mb-3">
                by Hemanta Sundaray | {new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)}
              </h6>
              <div className="col mb-3 post-border"></div>
              <p>{post.body}</p>
            </article>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <h3 className="text-center mt-5">POST NOT FOUND</h3>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ViewPost;
```

Comment: Where is the state defined?

Comment: this is supposed to happen. On browser refresh, your app is reinitialized along with your redux store. On page refresh, you can either re-fetch your data if you are using an external API or store your state in a non-volatile browser memory like local storage. You can also use redux-persist which will synchronize your redux state with the local storage.

Comment: When you refresh you have to get the post items all over again! I asssume state.posts has a list of posts which you fetch and then get a particular post from the list in the ViewPage component. When you refresh, that list of posts is lost and you have to fetch it again!

Comment: @ShreeCharan, Yes. I think I might have to use useEffect on the viewPost page to fetch that particular post and then save it in redux store and then use that in the component.

Comment: @hemanta you can have useEffect where you check if state.posts is empty and the fetch again if it is